# Как можно открыть 2Gis из своего приложения

Tags: java, android, 2gis-api

Как можно открыть 2Gis из своего приложения и сразу передать адреса(начальная точка и конечная) чтобы построить маршрут?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://help.2gis.ru/question/razrabotchikam-zapusk-mobilnogo-prilozheniya-2gis/android

**Как построить маршрут**

Если вам нужно построить маршрут, сформируйте URL следующим образом.

`dgis://2gis.ru/routeSearch/rsType/<type>/from/<lon>,<lat>/to/<lon>,<lat>`

- from/**<lon>,<lat>**  используется для
  задания точки старта,
- rsType/**<type>** используется для задания типа
  транспорта,
- to/**<lon>,<lat>** используется для задания
  точки

Используются следующие параметры:

- **type**, тип данных: string. Тип маршрута: car
  (автомобильный маршрут), ctx (общественный транспорт), pedestrian
  (пеший маршрут), taxi (маршрут на такси). Например, если параметр
  type/car, то строится маршрут с использованием
  автомобильного транспорта.
- **lon**, тип данных: float. Долгота.
- **lat**, тип данных: float. Широта.

Пример URL:
`dgis://2gis.ru/routeSearch/rsType/car/from/30.333494,59.947164/to/30.149939,59.849767`

При открытии этой ссылки в приложении 2ГИС у вас построится маршрут из центра Санкт-Петербурга.

Маршрут может строиться без указания начальной точки. В таком случае в качестве точки отправления подставляется текущее местоположение пользователя (если его возможно определить).

Пример URL:

`dgis://2gis.ru/routeSearch/rsType/car/to/30.149939,59.849767`

Comment: спасибо большое.Когда по гуглу нашел и открыл не хорошо просмотрел эту  страницу

Comment: @Азамат, Способ не позволяет обозначить точки, говорит что невозможно построить маршрут